# Openrowset with Spaces in source

Tags: database, excel, sql-server-2008, openrowset

I am attempting to load an Excel file into SQL Server using the OPENROWSET and I think I have narrowed my issue down to there being spaces in the file name. I am using the following Stored Procedure where the source is dynamically passed in:

```
    USE [MyDB]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[SP_LOAD_EXCEL]    Script Date: 08/07/2014 10:22:37 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
--Creates a Store Procedure to take a fully qualified file name and
--load to a temporary database

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_LOAD_EXCEL]
    @file nvarchar(max)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @Sql Nvarchar(max);

    SET @Sql = 'INSERT INTO [MyDB].[dbo].[ExcelData]
    SELECT *
    FROM OPENROWSET (''Microsoft.Ace.OLEDB.12.0''
    ,''Excel 12.0; Database='+@file +';Extended Properties=''''EXCEL 12.0;HDR=NO;IMEX=1''
    ,''SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]'')';

    EXEC(@Sql);

END
```

I am calling the SP with the following and this works:

```
USE [MyDB]
GO

DECLARE @return_value int

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[SP_LOAD_EXCEL]
        @file = N'E:\My_Finalised.xlsx'

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value

GO
```

However if I substitute the filename for E:\Database backups\My_Finalised.xlsx then it doesnt work.

So to summarize:

**WORKS**: E:\My_Finalised.xlsx
**DOESNT** WORK: E:\Database backups\My_Finalised.xlsx

How do I get OPENROWSET to accept a source that has spaces in it? Thanks

Comment: What is the error you are getting? OPENROWSET and OPENQUERY are both pretty finicky with syntax. I haven't tried it but my first thought is to try putting [] around the file name. If that doesn't work, can the name of the folder be changed?

Comment: I tried adding in the [] and also double-quoting and it keeps saying "External table is not in the expected format." but the file hasn't changed.

Comment: The tool gets called from a website by people uploading files and the file is copied to a server - so im not in full control of the path thats generated to be able to switch it. I have tried writing a method in C# which gets the Short Path Name instead(and this removes spaces) but it generates the same error.

Comment: Is there anyway it's a permissions issue? I know that isn't what the error implies but I've seen odder things  with Microsoft messages!

Comment: I went down the route of Permissions by running a tool called ProcMon but it was flooding the screen with that much data I couldn't find anything that said "Permission denied accessing file.." etc. But Ill have a look again.

On any other guides I've read it only ever mentions problems with spaces in the Sheet name, not the file name. So maybe I'm looking in the wrong place.

Comment: Another option would be to create a linked server to the spreadsheet then call that either directly or using OPENQUERY. I've created those with spaces in them. You'll need to be a sysadmin, setupadmin, control or have alter linked server permissions do create a linked server.